# Stack Pointer reading incorrect value from register

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, keil

Why is Stack-pointer register not reading correct value from another register? When I move a value from register (r0) to stack pointer (r13), the SP reads incorrect value.
This is what is mean:

```
MOV R0, 10
MOV R13, R0
```

In this case, "A" should move to R13 but instead it gets 8.
Similarly,

```
MOV R0, 9
MOV R13, R0
```

In this case R13 stores 8 instead of 9.

Here's a simple program program that demonstrates the problem,

```
void Init()
{               
    __asm(
        "LDR R0, =0x3FFFFDA7\n"
        "MOV R13, R0\n"
    );
}


int main(void)
{
    Init();     
    return (1);
}

void SystemInit(void)
{
}
```

Nothing much is going on here. Just a simple function call. Inside the function I moved the address to r0. Then I moved the address to R13(SP), but instead of actual address i.e. 0x3FFFFDA7, SP received 0x3FFFFDA4.
The images shows the disassembly,

[image]

So what is going on here? Why is Stack pointer Register reading incorrect values?

I am using ARM inline Assembly with C. The IDE is KEIL.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show a [mcve] actually using inline assembly.  The problem is most likely in your C and the compiler-generated code surrounding your inline asm.  Or debug it yourself by looking at the compiler output.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more docs, if KEIL uses GNU C inline asm syntax.

Comment: I've edited my question. Thanks

Comment: Are you in thumb mode? If so, reading the ARM architecture reference manual may enlighten you.

Comment: can you show the disassembly?

Comment: @old_timer I have added the image that shows the disassembly.

Comment: but not all of the relevant information is there and its an image just paste the text.  see how the instruction is loading the constant, you didnt show that constant.  And you are fully aware that you are going to likely crash the system, that is your goal yes?  What is your goal for moving the stack pointer when the thing that it returns to needs it?  and also the first access will be unaligned and depending on your settings might fault?

Comment: For the record, it works as expected in qemu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might find this helpful.

Stack-Pointer for armv7 must be 4 bytes aligned. You can write there 0,4,8,12,16 etc but not 9,10,F etc.

So if you want to move any value to Stack-Pointer, make sure it is 4 bytes aligned.